# Assert behaviour in java?

Tags: java

I am getting compilation error in Line 3, Is it any special case for asserts in java ? i am not sure why it's expecting some return type from methodB() , can somebody help me here ? Thanks

```
public class AssertTest {
    public void methodA(int i) {
        assert i >= 0 : methodB();
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public void methodB() {
        System.out.println("The value must not be negative");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        AssertTest test = new AssertTest();
        test.methodA(-10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The second form of the assertion statement is:
>
> ```
> assert Expression1 : Expression2 ;
> ```
>
> where:
>
> Expression1 is a boolean expression. Expression2 is an expression that
>   has a value. (It cannot be an invocation of a method that is declared
>   void.)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html

Basically, `Expression2` must return a value, not `void`.

Answer (score 9):

[The docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) are clear:

> Expression2 is an expression that has a value. (It cannot be an invocation of a method that is declared void.)
>
> Use this version of the assert statement to provide a detail message for the AssertionError. The system passes the value of Expression2 to the appropriate AssertionError constructor, which uses the string representation of the value as the error's detail message.

So, the return value from that method is used as the error message. In your case, instead of printing to the system out, just return the string.

Note that even when you make this code compile, it will print `-10`. Assertions are not enabled by default, so you have to [enable them](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html#enable-disable).

And next time when in doubt, consult the documentation first.

Answer (score 4):

It is simpler, and more readable, to merely place your error message directly in the `assert` statement:

```
assert (i >= 0) : "AssertTest: The value must not be negative.";
```

The Java system will display the message when the assert fires.

Answer (score 0):

Your method should have a return type.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html

Here is the relevant information from that link :

The second form of the assertion statement is:

```
assert Expression1 : Expression2 ;
```

where:

```
* Expression1 is a boolean expression.
* Expression2 is an expression that has a value. **(It cannot be an invocation of a method that is declared void.)**
```